# In .NET, how to identify if a C++ DLL is in DEBUG or RELEASE build?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, build, release

thanks to some resource of the web, I made a little tool to know whether my .NET dll is in debug or in release build; but I'd like it to work also for c/c++ DLLs.

Does anyone have some piece of code about this? The DLLs are compiled using Visual Studio.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847721/how-to-identify-if-a-library-is-debug-or-release-build

Comment: I saw this post already, and I am most a .NET developper thant a C++ developper, so I'm looking for a .net code

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way of telling such thing just looking at the DLL. In our work we use different names for debug dlls (adding a D at the end) and using preprocessor stuff.

As Debug or Release builds are just a set of properties for the compiler you could end up with a Debug build that compiles like a Release does and the other way around.

Summarizing, I think there is no way, sorry.

Comment: there must be some library or function import difference

Comment: It just depends on how you configure you Release or Debug configuration. They are just  a bunch of settings.

Comment: As he is configuring and building the C++ DLLs himself, he can make it work with the `FileVersionInfo.IsDebug` way.

Answer (score 1):

This is not 100% but take a look at this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.isdebug.aspx

Comment: The link is to check whether it contains the debug information. Not debug version. The release version also can contain the debug information

Comment: It didn't work. It returned false for a DLL built in Debug mode

Answer (score 0):

Information is usually contained in the [PE header](http://www.skynet.ie/~caolan/pub/winresdump/winresdump/doc/pefile.html). You can write some code for parsing it.

Comment: The Version Info block may also help.  Take a look the definition here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381058(VS.85).aspx.  I don't think anything will be 100% accurate though.

Comment: Have in mind that this would work in some cases but not it others as the configurations can be changed to whatever you want.